# Creating Faces from Edges for an n-shaped object

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes, edges, csv

I've recently started a project, for which I need some help.

What am I doing? I have a .csv containing real world coordinates(in decimal) in order to build a certain shape.

As of now, I've managed to extract my values to produce the shape I want with Vertecies and Edges:
[image: Node Tree]

[image: Sample of the shape]

What I need to do now is to make this whole thing a box.
My Attribute "H" contains the height which I'd like to use.
So I need some way of creating faces on all three axis(in order to get my Box) and the z-axis shall be extended according to the value "H".
"H" will always be positive, so extending upwards.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the meshes always a closed curve? If so you could use a "Mesh to Curve" > "Fill Curve"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create surfaces from edges in *Geometry Nodes*, you have two options:

1. Create a **curve** and use `Fill Curve`
2. Create a **mesh** primitive and move its points

### Curves

If you want to use curves, then one solution might look like this:

[image]

The principle should be what you are currently already using, but here I don't create a `Mesh Line`, but directly a `Curve Line`.

Then I resample it with the required number of points and move them to the desired positions.

Afterwards I apply `Fill Curve`, whereby I get a mesh with faces. Finally I just have to extrude them with the desired height.

### Mesh Circle

It is even easier to directly create a mesh with the required number of points.

This could look like this:

[image]

Here I simply create a `Mesh Circle`. This has the advantage that I can specify the required number of points already during the creation.

These are then also moved and the faces extruded.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This solved my problem.
I realized I just didn't catch that I simply could've replace the mesh line with a mesh circle :D There's been my fault^^